# Subtitle in <li> is not align with CSS inline

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, inline

I'm trying to make and following the best practices for email mailing, but I tried anyways align this "subtitle" of my < li > tag and fails every time.

I have this list on my PSD for email mailing:

[image: Name of Hotel and subtitle with the Address]

And this is my code:

```
<div style="width:600px; height:50px">
 <span style="color:#e2e478; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:14px; margin-left:23px; line-height:75px">HOTELES PARTICIPANTES</span>
</div>

<div style="width:600px; height:542px; color:#ffffff; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:13px;">
 <ul style="line-height:25px; columns:2">
  <li style="margin-left:7px;">Belmond La Samanna</li>
   <span>San Marino</span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Belmond Maroma Resort & Spa</li>
   <span>Riviera Maya, México</span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Belmond Casa de Sierra Nevada</li>
   <span>San Miguel de Allende, México </span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Belmond El Encanto</li>
   <span>Santa Bárbara, EE.UU.</span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Belmond Charleston Place </li>
   <span> Charleston, EE.UU.</span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Inn at Perry Cabin by Belmond</li>
   <span>St. Michaels, EE.UU.</span>
  <li style="margin-left:-7px;">Belmond Copacabana Palace</li>
   <span>Rio de Janeiro, Brazil </span>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Maybe this code has some errors, I'll appreciate all helps on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace `margin-left:-7px` with `margin-left:7px` and put `span` inside `li`

https://jsfiddle.net/MostafaB/u4dpa7e6/2/

Comment: Woww!! Perfect work my friend! By the way, how can I set the <span> near from the <li> line? They are separated just a little. @Mostafa

Comment: add this style : li span{display: block;  margin-top: -8px;}

Comment: That's nice! But when I add this style in my CSS inline, doesn't work... I have to develop my mailing all with css inline, do you know how do this? @Mostafa

Comment: try to add a class to the span "subtitle" for example and change the style like this : .subtitle{ display: block;  margin-top: -8px;}

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot my friend! o/

Answer (score 2):

it's not aligning because you are putting the text underneath in a separate span instead of the same wrapping `li` tag

original:
`<li style="margin-left:7px;">Belmond La Samanna</li><span>San Marino</span>`

new:

```
<li style="margin-left:7px;">Belmond La Samanna <br> <span>San Marino</span></li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know how can I set the subtitle near from the < li >? Because they are separated from each other. @Aldose

Comment: I'd suggest the `<br>` isn't needed here, as the `<span>` can be set to `display: block;`

Comment: If you go with @trnelson's suggestion of using display block for the span, you can simply use a negative margin to move the span up the desired amount
`<span style="margin-top:-7px">San Marino</span>`

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work:

```
<div style="background-color: black">

    <style>
    .title-bloc {
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .title {
        color: #e2e478;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 23px;
        line-height: 75px;
    }

    .list-container {
        width: 600px;
        height: 542px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    ul {
        line-height: 25px;
        columns: 2;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    li {
        color: #e2e478;
    }

    span {
        color: white;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="title-bloc">
        <span class="title">HOTELES PARTICIPANTES</span>
    </div>

    <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Belmond La Samanna<br>
                <span>San Marino</span></li>
            <li>Belmond Maroma Resort & Spa<br>
                <span>Riviera Maya, México</span></li>
            <li>Belmond Casa de Sierra Nevada<br>
                <span>San Miguel de Allende, México </span></li>
            <li>Belmond El Encanto<br>
                <span>Santa Bárbara, EE.UU.</span></li>
            <li>Belmond Charleston Place<br>
                <span> Charleston, EE.UU.</span></li>
            <li>Inn at Perry Cabin by Belmond<br>
                <span>St. Michaels, EE.UU.</span></li>
            <li>Belmond Copacabana Palace<br>
                <span>Rio de Janeiro, Brazil </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, lists are not very well supported by some email clients, especially Outlook. To get lists appearing correctly everywhere, best practice is to usually make them tables instead of using ul/li. For example:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td valign="top" style="color: #796e65; text-align:left;font-size:14px;line-height: 105%; padding: 0 4px 0 24px;">
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td style="color: #796e65; text-align:left;font-size:14px;line-height: 105%; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    ul {
        width: 500px;
    }

    li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.